# Unreal Engine 4.16, C++ Include header files

Tags: c++, header-files, unreal-engine4

I am using Unreal Engine 4.16 and Visual Studio 2017, and I am trying to import a class: "PhysicsEngine/PhysicsHandleComponent.h" and I get a lot of errors.

If I don't import it, everything works fine, builds properly, and everything, so the problem is isolated.

In the header file, Grabber.h, before including, I have this:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "Grabber.generated.h"

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BUILDINGESCAPE_API UGrabber : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    ...
```

And everything works.

But as soon as I include the correct header, like so:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "PhysicsEngine/PhysicsHandleComponent.h"
#include "Grabber.generated.h"

UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BUILDINGESCAPE_API UGrabber : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    ...
```

"UCLASS" (line 10) and "class" (line 11) get underlined, nothing will build, and it throws these errors:

```
E0077   this declaration has no storage class or type specifier ...\Grabber.h   10
E0065   expected a ';'  ...\Grabber.h   11
```

Why isn't it letting me import this file?

Edit: This is the correct file, correct spelling, and it is a file in the engine. I did not write it, so there is nothing wrong with "PhysicsEngine/PhysicsHandleComponent"

Comment: Does this link help at all, particularly the last post? https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/197994/grab-component-crash.html?lang=en-US

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I worked out that if you move the generated.h file onto a different line (By pressing enter above it) then you get the errors. Try using one of the blank lines above the #includes you already have. (You can move #pragma once if you need to)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error for a different header with both Unreal Engine 16.1 and Visual Studio 2017. While I'm not entirely sure what causes it, a solution is to simply move the import into the .cpp file, instead of the header (.h) file.

I believe it has something to do with the pre-compliled header unreal generates and visual studio may no longer see them correctly once we try to include different headers.